# How do I call a variable I made in Java without calling the package? (its in the same class)

Tags: java, variables, package

So this is my code:

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
Socket sock = new server.accept();
```

It says "server cannot be resolved to a type".
Well as you can see, I made a variable called "server". How can I use server.accept()?
Oh, and I tried `Socket sock = new this.server.accept();` and `Socket sock = new accept();` and `Socket sock = new this.accept();` but none of them work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to create a new object or call a method on an existing one? If you just want to use `server.accept()`, you need to remove the `new` before the method call:

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
Socket sock = server.accept();
```

The [`new` keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) is only used when you want to instantiate a type. Once you have an instance of that type, you never need to use the `new` again and can just call methods on it by using the variable containing that instance.

Currently the compiler is trying to use `server` as a type, which is why you're getting an error complaining about it not being resolved to one. :D

Answer (score 1):

The Java language expects `new` to be followed by a class name or an array type name, and says that you are creating a new object.

But you are not trying to create a new object here.  You are trying to call the `accept()` method on an existing object.

Get rid of the `new` on the 2nd line.

---

The reason for the somewhat confusing message is that the compiler *thinks* that you are trying to create an object, and is trying to match "server.accept" with a qualified class name; i.e. a class called "accept" in the "server" package.  Neither of these exist, so it says that it can't do it.  The reason that it doesn't realise that the "server" name is the name of your variable is that identifiers for variables and identifiers for classes and packages are in different namespaces.  To illustrate, if you defined a class as follows:

```
package server;
public class accept {
}
```

then your two line code snippet would give a different compilation error, along the lines of "you can't assign an object of type "server.accept" to a variable of type Socket".

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like the problem is the compiler can't resolve "ServerSocket".

Q: Where is this class defined?

One you allocate "server" (i.e. once you have an instance of "ServerSocket"), then you do NOT need to call "new".

SUGGESTED CHANGE:

```
import java.net.*;

public class MyClass {

  public void SomeMethod () {
    int port = SomeNumber;
    ...
    try {
      java.net.ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket (port);
      Socket clientSocket = socket.accept ();
      ...
```

Comment: hint: the compiler is not looking for ServerSocket, but "server"

Comment: @Yanick Rochon: Hint - I'm just trying to help.  Your "hints" (and your unwarranted downvotes) are not welcome :)

Comment: the first part of your answer is simply not correct, and I *was* kind enough to tell you why I downvoted. Which is far more than what I personally usually have.